# Python interface for DMK 23U274 USB camera for astrophotography

Tags: amateur-observing, photography, python

I have access to a monochrome USB camera (DMK 23U274, The Imaging Source) and I'd like to record focal plane images from a small telescope with a python script that would control it by setting exposure times and triggering image captures.

Ideally I would like to be able to do this running on a Windows or MacOS laptop or a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Linux but I don't know if that would require three different sets of special software in the middle (dll's or whatever).

Are there any platform-agnostic ways of doing this via USB? If not, are there Python solutions for amateur astronomers that can run on one or two of these platforms at least?

---

The only thing that I have found is this, but it specific to Windows and it seems to be an unfinished Python wrapper with unresolved memory leak issues:

- https://github.com/TheImagingSource/IC-Imaging-Control-Samples/tree/master/Python
- https://github.com/TheImagingSource/IC-Imaging-Control-Samples/issues/7

**update:** I've also found the following "Python wrapper for the IC Imaging Control SDK from The Imaging Source (TIS)" which "only works on Windows due to wrapping a DLL" so my hope for a platform-agnostic Python package is waning.

- https://github.com/morefigs/py-ic-imaging-control

Comment: I've also asked a more general question: [Python controllable amateur astrophotography cameras?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35690/7982)

Comment: Have you looked at the ASCOM project?